how is the trajectory point in ros2 written into struct "motion_data_" in abb_hardware_interface.cpp
i'm the beginner of ros2 and i'm using the abb_ros2 package to implement communication between Ros2 and ABB robots recently.i have a question about how trajectory point in ros2 are written into "motion_data_" with write in abb_hardware_interface.cpp
